# How to turn off netbeans welcome screen?

Tags: netbeans

The screen which shows whenever i start Netbeans is very annoying, and among the hundreds of options I can't find the one which turns it off?

Comment: The splash screen, or the welcome screen?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

To disable the welcome screen, all you have to do is uncheck the box at the bottom that says "Show on startup".

[image]

(If I misunderstood you and you were asking about the splash screen, you can disable it by [passing the -nosplash parameter](http://markmail.org/message/iblqiipmvwvytrvo).)

Comment: Thanks. Its hidden in such a corner that its impossible to see

Comment: In NetBeans 7.3 the checkbox has moved to the upper right corner of the start page. Even more impossible to notice.

Comment: Its surprising that for many years that I am using NetBeans and putting up with this StartUp annoying page, I didn't notice this checkbox. Finally thanks to this post now I have disabled it.

Comment: `NetBeans 8.0.2` is also like this.

Comment: `Netbeans 8.2` still is like this

Answer (score 2):

It could be complicated for 4k screen users, but it can be done in "blind" mode, by using TAB button to jump through menu and ENTER to uncheck the box.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I found an alternative way to solve the same problem on high resolution screens: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68344254/1277576

Answer (score 0):

As noted in another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35648606/1277576), that checkbox is impossible to see on high resolution screens (it is completely invisible).

The solution I found is to specify a small font size at Netbeans startup (using `--fontsize 14` as parameter), disable the checkbox and then restore the size I've been using all along, in my case `--fontsize 20`.